# New project language repartition

Tags: programming-languages

A few months ago I saw a pie chart of a study showing the trend in new projects as for the language of choice.

The study revealed that the leading language of choice was Java, then C++ then C, and so on. I'd like to find that study if anyone knows where to find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html